# Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888 & Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

When the Spring Cloud Dataflow Http-Source app Pod starts on kubernetes notice following two messages in console.

```
Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. 
Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/http-source/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException
```

How to get this resolved?

```
subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2019-09-15 05:17:26.773  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application-1.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2019-09-15 05:17:26.774  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2019-09-15 05:17:27.065  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2019-09-15 05:17:27.137  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
2019-09-15 05:17:27.141  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/http-source/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Comment: Hi, @techpro. Welcome to the SO club. I suggest that you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and related help pages.  Please - show what you have tried yourself and your step to reproduce the case. In short: please refer to [How to Ask and minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Yasen Thanks for valuable input on this question. It helps.

Comment: What commands did you run? What environment. Any detail can make a difference.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Do you want to connect TO cluster or FROM cluster? Also did you expose any endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully, the following message will be logged as a `WARN` in the logs.

```
Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. 
Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/http-source/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException
```

You'd see this `WARN` message for all the apps that we ship, SCDF, and Skipper servers that runs on K8s. This means that the apps, SCDF or Skipper don't have a `config-server` configured, so it defaults to the default `http://localhost:8888`.

*Background*: we provide the `config-server` dependency in all the apps that we ship to help you get started with it quickly.

If you don't use the config-server, that's fine; it will not cause any harm - nothing to worry, however.

Comment: Thank you, Sabby. Makes sense.

Comment: @SabbyAnandan I have a same problem running Spring Boot Microservices on Kubernetes. Can you help me if you have any idea about it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173708/kubernetes-issue-in-spring-boot-microservices-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-c