# Kubernetes Issue in Spring Boot Microservices java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, devops, minikube

I have a problem about running Spring Boot Microservices on Kubernetes. After I installed minikube, I started it and open its dashboard.

Here is the commands to open dashboards.

```
1 ) minikube start
2 ) minikube dashboard
```

Next, I run all services through this command.

```
kubectl apply -f k8s
```

After waiting for a certain amount of time, I got this issue shown below.

```
15:22:37.395 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientFailFastException: Could not locate PropertySource and the resource is not optional, failing
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.doLoad(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:197)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.load(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:102)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.load(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:61)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:116)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processWithProfiles(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:311)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:232)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
 at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
 at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
 at com.microservice.orderservice.OrderServiceApplication.main(OrderServiceApplication.java:15)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server-svc:9296/ORDER-SERVICE/default": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:303)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.doLoad(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:118)
 ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
 at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
 at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:508)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:276)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:375)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:396)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
 at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
 at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
 at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
 ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Here is my deployment.yaml file shown below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-service-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-service-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-service-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-service-app
          image: noyandocker/authservice
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7777
          env:
            - name: CONFIG_SERVER_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: config-cm
                  key: config_url
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-cm
                  key: hostname

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-service-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-service-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 7777
```

Here is the config map yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-cm
data:
  config_url: "config-server-svc"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: eureka-cm
data:
  eureka_service_address: "http://eureka-0.eureka:8761/eureka"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-cm
data:
  hostname: "mysql-0.mysql"
```

Here is the config-server-deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: config-server-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: config-server-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: config-server-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: config-server-app
          image: noyandocker/configserver
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9296
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 9296
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 3
            failureThreshold: 2
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 9296
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 8
            failureThreshold: 1
          env:
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: config-server-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: config-server-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9296
```

I thought all the services will start simultaneously. Config Server is the Dependent Service for all other Serivces like auth service and this Auth service should not start until Config Server service is up and running.

**Edited**

Someone said the message to me.

IN Kubernetes all the services will start simultaneously. Config Server is the Dependent Service for all other Services. i.e Order, Payment, and Product.

Sp Ideally your Order service should not start until the COnfig Server service is up and running. We saw a similar thing implemented in Docker using Depends_on properties.

IN Kubernetes, We can implement it using Probes. You need to implement Lineness and Readiness probe for your application for Config Server.

You add a Config for Order Service that checks that Config Server is Up or not and then it will start.

I still couldn't fix the issue.

How can I do that?

Here is my repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer)

Here is my docker hub : [Link](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=noyandocker)

Here is git backend system : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springappconfig)

Comment: Hey, I'm also stuck with on the docker section. In the order services, what should I pass in place of DB_SERVER env variable while running the docker? I've created one group for this course by daily code buffer. You can join via the following link:
Discord: https://discord.gg/FVUgRxCw
Telegram: https://t.me/+PP7q6Fq4AeQ0ZTg1

Answer (score 0):

When working in a microservices architecture, you can't rely on dependencies between services. What if a single service shuts down due to hardware problems? All the platform will be unavailable?

In fact, each microservice must be prepared to unavailable services. You can do it with Circuit Breaker. As far as I know, Kubernetes doesn't support this kind of dependency.

Nevertheless, I've found some hacks that can be used here: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/kubernetes-demystified-solving-service-dependencies_594110

In your case, with the Service Config Server which is unavailable when starting the other services, you can add some retry mechanism to the services. This way, they will try to reach the Service Config Server after 5 or 5 attempts. Take a look here, https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.1.4.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#config-client-retry

Comment: I added health check for this purpose to check whether if it up or not. I still couldn't solve it. Is it possible to test it if you have any information about it?

Comment: I couldn't fix it. Can you look through the deployment.yaml file if you don't mind?

Comment: What's the problem now? Do the config service start but too late?

Comment: Config server starts but I think it works a bit lately. Can you test it if you don't mind? I also edited my post.

Comment: I don't see a bootstrap configuration (in orderservice) file which contains the Config Server connection. In this file, you should add the "retry" configuration I've explained in the last paragraph.

Comment: I can run all services in local and on Docker. There is no problem for them. I defined health for each service in Kubernetes deployment yaml file not it didn't work.

Comment: I don't mean in Kubernetes, but in Spring Boot, can you add this configuration https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.1.4.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#config-client-retry in orderservice?

Comment: I still couldn't fix it. Can you test it if you don't mind?